# How can I configure different OAuth2 providers for different routes in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm building a Spring Boot application that has two sets of routes: one for CMS-related functionality that should use Amazon Cognito for authentication, and another for app-related functionality that should use Firebase Authentication.

I've already set up the basic Spring Security configuration for OAuth2 authentication, but I'm not sure how to configure different OAuth2 providers for different sets of routes.

Here's what my current configuration looks like:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var memberRepository: MemberRepository


    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        return http
            .authorizeHttpRequests { authorize ->
                authorize
                    .antMatchers("/cms/**").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/app/**").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
            }
            .oauth2ResourceServer { oauth2 ->
                oauth2
                    .jwt { jwt ->
                        jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(AwsCognitoJwtAuthenticationConverter(memberRepository))
                    }
            }.build()
    }
}
```

As you can see, the authorizeRequests section is currently set up to require authentication for all routes under /cms and /app. However, I want to use Amazon Cognito for the /cms routes and Firebase Authentication for the /app routes.

How can I configure Spring Security to use different OAuth2 providers for different sets of routes?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

How can I add multiple resource servers to the application.yml?

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/...
```

Edit:
My project is a simple REST API for a CMS (customer management system) and a mobile app. User login and registration happens exclusively through the client and Firebase Authentication on the mobile app, and AWS Cognito via NextAuth for the CMS, which is a Next.js web app. The REST API should check if all routes starting with "/cms" have a valid bearer token using Cognito and check if all routes starting with "/app" have a valid bearer token using Firebase Authentication. Maybe there is an easier solution to this, but Im pretty new to spring boot.

Comment: How can i add multiple resource server/issuer uris in the yml then?

Comment: Actually, there is a "way in `application.yaml`" , but with an alternate Spring Boot starter, as I described in this tutorial: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken

Answer (score 2):

You are in a multi-tenant scenario and should override the `AuthenticationManagerResolver` instead of just the Authentication converter.

```java
http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.authenticationManagerResolver(...));
```

This bean you configure there could switch from a "Cognito" authentication manager to a "Firebase" one depending on the issuer of the JWT.

I detailed two solutions in [this tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken): one with 0 Java conf (only properties) is using a Spring Boot starter of mine and the other with the "official" starter.

Note that with the solutions I expose there, both Cognito and Firebase identities will be accepted on all routes (but you can still check roles or even issuer in `@PreAuthorize` rules). If this is not acceptable to you, then define a security filter-chain bean for each route (use for instance `http.securityMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/cms/**"))`) and throw an exception in the Authentication manager resolver if the issuer is not the one you expect for that route.

But, in the case where each route should accept only one issuer, maybe should you consider splitting your application in two, each with standard single tenant configuration?

Comment: Okay I have edited the question, do you still think that is the only solution to this problem?

Comment: I proposed 3 solutions and 2 are still applicable for your edited question (only one identity source for each path matcher): separated `SecurityFilterChain` beans with `securityMatcher` and split `/cms` and `/app` in different applications. The second option is simpler, more scalable and more fault tolerant.